# How to display all the phone contacts (name, phone number) in a textView or String?

Tags: android

```
public class ImportContactsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.con);
        String msg = "";

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
                String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
                String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID));

                msg += name + " " + number + " " + email + "\n";
        }
        txt.setText(msg.toString());
    }
}
```

I am developing an application in which the application is able to send an email containing all the current phone contacts (name + phone number) as a backup alternative. I am trying out on how to extract all the phone contacts information and display them on the TextView... But I cannot do it, someone please consult me. Thanks...

```
LogCat
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.example.importcontacts/com.example.importcontacts.ImportContactsActivity} : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' does not exist
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' does not exist
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:267)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at com.example.importcontacts.ImportContactsActivity.onCreate(ImportContactsActivity.java:46)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-09 15:22:48.634: E/AndroidRuntime(680):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is the problem?are you getting any error?if so posting logcat log would be useful,if not please describe in detail what is your problem,thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` instead of `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` so that you can get the phone number, and change these lines

```
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));
String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID));
```

to

```
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER));
```

You will need another query to get the email_id. From the first cursor you can get the contact id like so

```
long contactId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.CONTACT_ID));
```

Now query the email uri using the `contactId` in your filter

```
long emailId;
Cursor cur = getContentResolver()
                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                     new String[]{"_id"},
                     "contact_id = " + contactId,
                     null,null);
if(cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()){
    emailId = cur.getLong(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it really works!!! But what if a particular contact contains more than one phone number, how am I going to extract the numbers out?

Comment: `Phone.CONTENT_URI` will give you a list of all the phone numbers stored, i.e every row is a phone number, not a contact. To find the contact a phone number belongs to, you use the contact_id